# sshd_config , added AllowGroups sshusers but users can still ssh

Tags: permissions, ssh, sshd

I changed /etc/ssh/sshd_config  and added line `AllowGroups sshusers` but all users can still ssh. (I tried also `AllowUsers` and `DenyUsers`, but it seems that it is the same. The config is completely ignored. Users can still ssh, even if I specifically mention them in `DenyUsers`.)

I have restarted ssh/sshd service   `sudo systemctl restart sshd/ssh` after every change in config.

And of course, users that are to be allowed are added to sshusers group, others are not.

Config is not being rewritten, my input is still there.

It is probably being overwritten by something else, but what?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the configuration overriden via `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/some-file-in-here.conf`?
Also note the order/override of processing: https://serverfault.com/a/617087

Comment: Thanks. `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d` does not exist.  serverfault.com/a/617087 is about precedence if there are multiple  "allows/denys" in my case it doesnt work even in case if there is only one.